# How to seemlessly switch between cursor and directional (WASD, arrows, gamepad) navigation and retain selected button

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, input

I am not sure why, but Unity treats a selectable (ie a button) being selected by directional navigation (ie WASD) and being selected by mousing over the selectable differently, as two separate states.

This means that if you are mousing over a button and press a directional button, you'll end up with one button being HIGHLIGHTED (mouse) and another being SELECTED (directional), so it looks like you have two buttons "selected", but when you press submit, the SELECTED button gets submitted.

It looks confusing and because a highligted button doesnt set the currentSelectedGameObject in the event system, I cant easily remove the "leftover" highlight in a straightforward manner.

I searched for a solution but found none that worked for me, so I'm posting my findings here in case anyone stumbles on this in the future with a similar problem:

---

## Desired Behaviour:

I'd like users to have the ability to switch between using mouse, keyboard and gamepad controls, and in turn, seamlessly switch between navigating via mouse cursor and directional (WASD/Dpad).

- when switching from cursor to directional, if nothing was selected, I want the first button on the screen selected*
- when switching from cursor to directional, if something was selected, I want navigation to continue from there (ie if you have the 3th button selected, I want to select button 2 if I pressed UP)
- when switching from directional to cursor, just lose all selection because chances are your mouse is not already hovered on anything anyway

- *I have a script that sets which button is this "first to be selected" button on every screen.*

## My Solution

In essence, I trigger the OnSelect event on PointerEnter, and trigger OnDeselect on PointerExit on every Selectable, and when on switching to directional input (detecting WASD/arrows/dpad etc), I clamp the mouse's movement area to go around the limitation that you cannot move the mouse pointer because it's handled by the OS.

I'm using [*Rewired*](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/rewired-21676) and when switching inputs, I fire an event that sets the width and height of the mouse's "movement area" to 0:

[image]

in this last GIF, you're seeing me changing my input between mouse and keyboard input and how switching to directional input changes movement area height/width to 0:

[image]

Doing only this does not remove the highlight the mouse hover leaves however, most probably because changing this movement area likely "teleports" the cursor instead of moving it, so it does not trigger pointerexit on the button, but you can overcome this by having a script on every selectable that essentially just triggers the selected button state on mouse over (**note that I am using a UI manager so the below code might not be perfect for your needs, I have not tested it but this is in essence the core of it**):

```
    public class ForceSelectedState: MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {
        public UnityEngine.UI.Button button;
     
        public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData) {
            button.OnSelect(eventData);
        }
     
        public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData) {
            button.OnDeselect(eventData);
        }
    }
```

Then you have to make sure this script is on all the Selectables everywhere.

## Results

In both of the following GIFs, I am mousing over a button then pressing arrow keys up/down before moving the mouse again:

**Default behaviour:**

[image]

**New behaviour:**

[image]

I'm not sure how you'd clamp mouse movement area without Rewired, I know you can't move the mouse via code because it's handled by the OS and it's a read-only value, but I'm sure there is some way without Rewired as well.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: _"I'd like users to have the ability to switch between using mouse, keyboard and gamepad controls"_ - I thought Unity can do this already where physical inputs are mapped to logical controls.  It's the latter your code is bound to such that it doesn't care how the **Fire** button was pressed and by what.  I'm not across the new input system but reason suggests a similar concept would be present.  I'm confused by the rest of your post.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, MickyD! I'm also confused by your post - I am not using the new input system. Could you elaborate on which parts of my post specifically you found confusing?

Comment: Oh! You're using a 3rd party add-on from the _Unity Asset Store_.  I've edited your post to make that more obvious.

Comment: I'd raise a bug report with the publisher.

Comment: The default behaviour as per the first gif is not a bug, it is intended behaviour by Unity. They treat "button moused over" (highlight) and "button navigated to via directional means like wasd" (select) as two different states.

My goal was to essentially unify these so when switching between cursor and directional navigation, you dont end up with one button being highlighted and the other being selected.